# Keras RNN (GRU, LSTM) produces plateau and then improvement

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to Keras (with TensorFlow backend) and am using it to do some simple sentiment analysis on user reviews. For some reason, my recurrent neural network is producing some unusual results that I do not understand.

**First**, my data is a straight-forward sentiment analysis training and test set from the [UCI ML archive](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Sentiment+Labelled+Sentences). There were 2061 training instances, which is small. The data looks like this:

```
                                                text  label
0  So there is no way for me to plug it in here i...      0
1                        Good case, Excellent value.      1
2                             Great for the jawbone.      1
3  Tied to charger for conversations lasting more...      0
4                                  The mic is great.      1
```

**Second**, here is a FFNN implementation that produces good results.

```py
# FFNN model.

# Build the model.
model_ffnn = Sequential()
model_ffnn.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=V, output_dim=32))
model_ffnn.add(layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
model_ffnn.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model_ffnn.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_ffnn.summary()

# Compile and train.
model_ffnn.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
EPOCHS = 50
history_ffnn = model_ffnn.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS,
                              batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2, verbose=3)
```

As you can see, the learning curves produce a smooth improvement as the number of epochs increases.

[image]

**Third**, here is the problem. I trained a recurrent neural network with a GRU, as shown below. I also tried an LSTM and saw the same results.

```py
# GRU model.

# Build the model.
model_gru = Sequential()
model_gru.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=V, output_dim=32))
model_gru.add(layers.GRU(units=32))
model_gru.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_gru.summary()

# Compile and train.
model_gru.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
EPOCHS = 50
history_gru = model_gru.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS,
                            batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2, verbose=3)
```

However, the learning curves are quite unusual. You can see a plateau where neither the loss nor the accuracy improve up to about epoch 17, and then the model starts learning and improving. I have never seen this type of plateau at the start of training before.

**Can anyone explain why this plateau is occurring, why it stops and gives way to gradual learning, and how I can avoid it?**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried different learning rates? https://keras.io/optimizers/

Comment: @GergesDib: Thanks. I posted an answer below. Does it follow your intuition?

Comment: yes looks about right.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment by @Gerges Dib, I tried out different learning rates in increasing order.

`lr = 0.0001`

[image]

`lr = 0.001` (the default learning rate for RMSprop)

[image]

`lr = 0.01`

[image]

`lr = 0.05`

[image]

`lr = 0.1`

[image]

This is very interesting. It looks like the plateau was caused by the optimizer's learning rate being too low. The parameters were stuck in a local optima until it could break out. I have not seen this pattern before.